# Pronunciation: "I love you" and "isle of view"

Tags: pronunciation

How are "I love you" and "isle of view" pronunced? I ask because I'm not able to distinguish the differences, but surely an English mother tongue can, presumably in less than a fifth of a second.

Comment: Piers Anthony, author of Xanth novels likes to make puns.  One of the Xanth novels is called 'Isle of View' which (deliberately) confuses everybody who hears it spoken, but does not see it written.

Comment: They're clearly distinct *if I say them clearly and distinctly*.  In casual conversation, however, I rarely do so, and although the two probably *are* different in a couple ways, I wouldn't expect anyone to be able to tell them apart unless I put special effort into it.

Comment: I want to know how do we call this game?
does anybody can answer ? another example of this is - My konjac son which is also Michael Jackson .

Answer (score 9):

There are two closely related differences between the two:

- **Vowel quality**: *of* contains a [**reduced**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction) vowel (an unstressed vowel ‘bleached’ of distinctive acoustic quality, conventionally represented as /ə/), while *love* contains a full vowel. Just what that full vowel is will vary between dialects and idiolects, but it will always be longer sustained than the reduced vowel, and it is capable of bearing stress.
- **Prosody**: *isle of view* (supposing that meant something!—perhaps we should recast it as *aisle of view*, which might make sense in, say, theatre architecture) would have a fixed prosodic contour: first and third syllables equally stressed and pitched, with a minimal *o’* between them. **/'aɪlə'vjuː/** (or in my dialect, /'a:lə'vjuː/

  *I love you*, on the other hand, is a capable of a variety of contours: any word might be stressed, or any two, or all three, and pitch may vary similarly. This in turn will have various impact on the syllable junctions, particularly the articulation of the /vj/ collocation: either /v/ or /j/ may be sustained, and /v/ may or may not close the preceding syllable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to keep it simple (not that I can go too complex, anyway).

## The *'I L[..ove]'* and *'Isle'*.

When pronouncing *isle*, there's a tiny 'drop' between the **i** sound and the **el**. *Ah-yel* is a good approximation; notice how the **i** sound is pretty distinguishable, almost a **y**. (I'm intentionally avoiding [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)).

On the other hand, most people, when pronouncing *I love you* on-the-fly, will not stress the **i**; if you try to say it out loud at a moderate speed, it'll sound like *ah love...*

## The *'Of View'*.

*Of view* has the *v* sound much more stressed and paused at (because the *f* approximates to *v*). The *e* in *view* is a bit stretched, which isn't the case in *you*.

## Pauses.

Most people will pause between *isle* and *of view*. *I love you* is much lighter and has almost no pauses.

## Overall.

*I love you*: ah-love-you.

*Isle of view*: ahyel ov-view.